# Setuptools generated compilation command incorrectly specifying library directories

Tags: python, gcc, setuptools

After running `python3 setup.py build_ext`, the following command is generated throughout the build sequence:

`arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ ... \
-L=/opt/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/ \
-L=/opt/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/lib/ \
-lpython3.5m \
-o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/kiwisolver.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

which produces the following errors:

```
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lpython3.5m
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lm
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lc
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crtendS.o: No such file or directory
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
```

However, when I replace the `-L=` with `-L`, the errors are reduced down to:

```
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
/opt/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.4.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc
```

Why does setuptools generate flags for library directories with `-L=/path/` rather than `-L/path/`?

Here is my `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension


ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        'kiwisolver',
        ['py/kiwisolver.cpp',
         'py/constraint.cpp',
         'py/expression.cpp',
         'py/solver.cpp',
         'py/strength.cpp',
         'py/term.cpp',
         'py/variable.cpp'],
        include_dirs=[
            '.',
            '/opt/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/python3.5m/'
        ],
        library_dirs=[
            '/opt/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/',
            '/opt/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/lib/'
        ],
        language='c++',
        extra_compiler_args=[
            "--verbose"
        ]
    ),
]


setup(
    name='kiwisolver',
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```

Comment: What's your setup file look like?

Comment: I've added that to the question now, @MadPhysicist

Comment: Python version? setuptools version?

Comment: @phd Python3.5.2 and setuptools version `40.0.0.post20180725.post-20180725`